# High school MCQ (geometry) about maximum of sine of an angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

No calculus is allowed in this question.

Also, it is not allowed to use any compound angle formulas such as

$\sin(A-B) =\sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B$.

How to find the greatest value of $\sin \angle APB$?

I attempted by consider the difference between angles $\angle OPB$ and $\angle OPA$ but I do now know how to make use of the fact that $P$ makes the angle greatest.

[image]

Comment: Where is this question from? This is a difficult question for high school level, and not being able to use angle sum formulas makes this very restrictive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall from [extended sine-rule](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sine-rule/#extended-sine-rule),
$$\sin \angle APB = \frac{AB}{2R_{\triangle APB}}$$

Since $AB$ is fixed, to maximize $\sin \angle APB$, we have to minimize the circumradius $R_{\triangle APB}$. As the circumcenter $S$ lies on perpendicular bisector of $AB$, $R_{\triangle APB}$ will be least when $SP \perp OC$ as in the following diagram.

[image]

Using that $SPOD$ is a rectangle and $A$ is mid of $OB$,

$$\text{max of sin} \angle APB = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: I still do not understand why the first formula $\sin \angle APB = AB/2R_{\triangle APB}$. I think this may be related to $\sin 90 =1$ but I cannot figure out from your sketch. Thanks.

Comment: @nam See [this link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sine-rule/#extended-sine-rule) for the statement of the extended-sine-rule as well as its proof. You can draw a quick diagram and check why it is true.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a geometric solution and may not be the most recommended approach but meets the condition of not using calculus and no compound angle formula.

As $\angle APB \lt 90^0,$ maximizing $\sin \angle APB \ $ will maximize $\angle APB$.

Say $OA = AB = a, OP = k \cdot a \ $ ($k \gt 0)$

Equating the  area of $\triangle APB$ and $\triangle OAP$

$\frac{1}{2} AP \cdot BP \sin \angle APB = \frac{1}{2} OP \cdot OA$

$\sin \angle APB = \displaystyle \frac{k \cdot a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2a^2} \cdot {\sqrt{4a^2+k^2a^2}}} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^4+5k^2+4}}$

$ = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+\frac{4}{k^2}+5}}$

$\sin \angle APB$ is maximum when $k^2+\frac{4}{k^2}$ is minimum.

Now by A.M-G.M, $k^2+\frac{4}{k^2} \geq 4$

Hence $\sin \angle APB = \displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Another approach:

In figure OC=OB. As canbe seen $\APB$ is maximum when P is at distance $\frac 34 OC$. You can find that:

$AD=\frac{\sqrt 2}4 OB$

$AC=\frac{\sqrt 5}2 OB$

$\sin (\angle ABC)=\frac {AD}{AC}\approx 0.316$

$\sin (\angle APB)>0.316$

So option $\frac 13\approx 0.3333>0.316$ is corect.